# Back Button Bug withjQuery hashchange event and animate scrollTop

Tags: jquery, back-button, scrolltop, hashtag

I'm not sure if this is a bug or the way wrote it but any help with be great!!

I am using jQuery hashchange event from Ben Alman which I have used in other projects for

hashevents using fadeto animations and had no issues. With this file here, I have a one-page

site and using the scrollTop function. The back button works but it only works once and the

foward button doesnt work at all, then it jumps back and forth but doesn't animate. Below is

what I currently have.

CSS:

```
         <nav id="primary">
            <ul>
                <li>
                 <a href="#home">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#about">about</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#services">services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#contact">contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </nav>


        <div id="content">
            <article id="home">home</article>
            <article id="about">about</article>
            <article id="services">services</article>
            <article id="contact">contact</article>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    var href         = '';
    var easeDuration = 1000;
    var easeType     = "easeOutExpo";

    //Thumbanil click states/////
$('#primary ul').delegate('li', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
            var index = $(this).prevAll().length;
    href =  $('#primary ul li a:eq(' + index + ')').attr('href');
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(href).offset().top},{easing: easeType,duration: easeDuration,complete: function() { 
            window.location.hash = href;
            return false;
            }});
        });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
              $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+newHash).offset().top}, {easing: easeType,duration: easeDuration,complete: function() { 
                return false;}});
  });
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var href         = '';
var easeDuration = 1000;
var easeType     = "easeOutExpo";
$(window).hashchange(function(){
//your code
});
});
```